# How do make autocompletion (Coc) work on Tab instead of Enter?

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-coc

I use [Coc-Python](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python) for Python autocompletions. It completes on Enter, however, I want to complete only on pressing Tab and reserve Enter for its normal behavior which is entering a new line. How do I do that?

Comment: The core CoC site on Github has an example configuration that I'm pretty sure does exactly what you're talking about. (OOC, did u recently install CoC-Python or have u had it for a while?)

Comment: @BLayer Just installed. Pretty much new to Vim in general :)

Comment: Hi. No problem. Welcome to Vi&Vim SE. But take a look at the first line of the CoC-Python readme. It's a warning that recommends using CoC-Pyright (assuming you're using Python 3)...CoC-Python is archived and it says it's "too hard to maintain".

Comment: @BLayer Oh, okay. Thanks!

Comment: @BLayer it is not related to the topic. Anyway put this in your vimrc or init.vim to use tab to navigate between completion results inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"

Comment: @TheVimmer Hmm. You seem to have mistaken me for someone who needs guidance on what kind of comments are appropriate. Rest assured I have a pretty good handle on how things work here. Mmm kay?

Comment: the core CoC site on Github example configuration doesn't work for me, any better ideas?